# Ba'al HaBayis accepting Shabbos early

Tags: halacha, shabbat

What is the *halachic* implication when the *Ba'al HaBayis* ("Man of the House"), as an individual and not the entire community, accepts *Shabbos* (Sabbath) early? Are his wife and children automatically bound to commence *Shabbos* at that point or are they able to start at the normal time? Does it make a difference if he accepts it on the condition that his family need not? Does it make a difference if he is absent (i.e. at *Shul*) but perhaps they are bound when he arrives home? [With sources please :)]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No they are not bound. Even when he arrives home *milachah* may still be done although not personally for his own benefit.

[Igros Moshe O.C. III Siman 38](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=335)

Comment: Although try explaining "it's shabbos for Daddy but not Mommy" (or vice versa) to your little kids.  While not a prohibition, I heard an experienced rabbi recommend that a couple try to set one standard that the kids can see.

Comment: Shalom, you are right that it is difficult to explain to the little children. One understanding of "Derech Eretz Kadmah LiTorah" is "Common Sense is necessary for Torah application." :-)